# Welche Form ist in diesem Satz richtig? "regelmäßiger" oder "regelmäßigen"?

Tags: dative, accusative

Welcher der beiden Sätze ist richtig? / Which one of these two sentences is correct?

- Er ist einer meiner regelmäßiger Kunden.
- Er ist einer meiner regelmäßigen Kunden.

Answer (score 4):

In the male form the correct way of spelling it is:

> Er ist einer meiner regelmäßigen Kunden.

You use plural for "regelmäßigen" here, because you refer to a single "Kunde" out of a set of multiple "Kunden". He is "one of many" so to speak.
If you were to adress him alone without reference of others, you could say:

> Er ist ein regelmäßiger Kunde.

Answer (score 3):

With respect to adjective declension, the possessive "meiner" behaves like an article. This means that the following adjective must be weakly inflected:

> Er ist einer meiner *regelmäßigen* Kunden.

Without the "meiner", strong inflection applies. E.g.:

> Dies ist ein typisches Verhalten *regelmäßiger* Kunden.

But with an article instead of a possessive, weak inflection would still apply:

> Er ist einer der *regelmäßigen* Kunden.